# Id compuesto en migración de Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

Tengo una tabla con un id compuesto:

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_language` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


    ALTER TABLE `profiles`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id_user`,`id_language`),
      ADD KEY `id_language` (`id_language`),
      ADD KEY `id_user` (`id_user`);

ALTER TABLE `profiles`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `profiles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `profiles_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_language`) REFERENCES `languages` (`id`);




INSERT INTO `profiles` (`id`, `id_user`, `id_language`) VALUES
('1-co', 1, 'co');
```

pero no se como hacer lo mismo en laravel

voy aqui:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->unsigned();

            //aqui deberia deicr que id es compuesta por id_user y id_langauge
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned();            
            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('id_language')->unsigned();            
            $table->foreign('id_language')->references('id')->on('languages');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

Pero no se que mas hacer.

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero creo no hay soporte para llaves compuestas, igual espera a la participación de otros usuarios

Comment: @element en el down, debería agregar tambien la tabla de la que heredo o así esta bien?

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto Eloquent no permite utilizar dos llaves primarias, hay varias formas que han planteado para que funciona, haciendo override de ciertos métodos, pero Eloquent como tal no fue diseñado para trabajar con llaves primarias compuestas.

Puedes ver la discusión en GitHub (desde 2014) en el siguiente enlace: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355

Si buscas un poco en Google, podrás encontrar algunas soluciones alternativas, incluso creo que hay algunos paquetes para Eloquent.