# Clave ajena compuesta en Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8, sqlite3

Estoy implementando una BBDD para SQLite con Laravel 8, tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
    public function up() {
    Schema::create('school', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table -> increments('id');
        $table -> string('name');
        $table -> string('address');
        $table -> string('location');
        $table -> string('province');
        $table -> string('phone');
        $table -> string('postal_code');
        $table -> string('web_site');
        $table -> timestamps();
    });
}

public function up() {
    Schema::create('course', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table -> integer('school');
        $table -> integer('number');
        $table -> enum('degree', array('preschool', 'primary', 'secundary', 'bachelor'));
        $table -> primary(['school', 'number', 'degree']);
        $table -> foreign('school') -> references('id') -> on('school') -> onDelete('cascade');
        $table -> timestamps();
    });
}

public function up() {
    Schema::create('group', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table -> string('group_words', 1);
        $table -> integer('course_number');
        $table -> string('course_degree');
        $table -> primary('group_words', 'course_number', 'course_degree');
        $table -> foreign(['course_number', 'course_degree']) -> references(['number', 'degree']) -> on('course') -> onDelete('cascade');
        $table -> timestamps();
    });
}
```

Y estos modelos:

1. Course, que a la hora de generar datos con Shool funciona correctamente:

   ```
    class Course extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'course';
    protected $fillable = ['school', 'number', 'degree'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function school() {
        return $this -> hasOne('App\Models\School');
    }

    public function group() {
        return $this -> hasMany('App\Models\Group');
    }
   ```

   }
2. Group, que se produce un error a la hora de generar los datos con el Seed:

   ```
    class Group extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'group';
    protected $fillable = ['group_words', 'course_number', 'course_degree'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function course() {
        return $this -> belongsTo('App\Models\Course', ['course_number', 'course_degree']);
    }
   ```

   }

El error que se muestra es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, la tabla Group tiene una clave ajena de Course formada por una tubla, quisiese saber si esto se puede hacer y, en caso de no poderse, como podría refactorizar la implementación para que funcionase correctamente.

He probado a separar los campos en 2 claves ajenas distintas, pero no ha servido.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Id compuesto en migración de Laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239237/id-compuesto-en-migraci%c3%b3n-de-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una llave foranea debe referenciar una columna (o conjunto de columnas) sujetas colectivamente a una restricción única o tener un índice único. [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes).

En tu caso la llave foranea en la tabla group referencia las columnas number y degree en la tabla course pero no hay una restricción de unicidad sobre ambas columnas conjuntamente (en la tabla course); o sea que puede haber dos filas con valores "number: 1, degree: preschool" en la tabla course (para distintas escuelas) como sabría a cual de las dos referencia la misma.

Como la llave primaria en course es 'school', 'number' y 'degree', una solución sería agregar school en la llave foranea; de esa manera sabría a que fila está referenciando la llave foranea (ya que habría una única fila en course con esos tres valores).

Según mi experiencia lo mejor es definir siempre llaves primarias sobre una columna ID autoincremental (en cada taba), y no utilizar datos que pertenecen al modelo.

[Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/442909/218615) puedes leer porque según mi opinión no es conveniente utilizar datos del modelo como llave primaria.

Comment: ¿Entonces crees que es mejor que identifique el curso con un ID? Lo que no quiero es arrastrar el colegio al resto de tablas y había pensado que usando una clave alternativa podría funcionar también para la tabla course, pero con la combinación de unique y nullable no consigo que me deje insertar más de un colegio en la tabla de los cursos.

Comment: Si, creo que es la mejor opción (simplifica mucho las cosas). En este caso deberías establecer una restricción de unicidad en  curso sobre 'school', 'number' y 'degree' para que no inserten duplicados (dicha restricción antes te la proveía la PK).

Comment: Sería dejarlo así: $table -> unique(array('school', 'degree', 'number')); ¿verdad?

Comment: Si (para definir la restricción de unicidad sobre esas tres columnas conjuntamente).